# Pandas 5yr & 10yr Moving average

Tags: pandas, moving-average

I have a dataframe where my index is datetime dtype but the dates are not in any sequential ordering. I am looking to calculate the 5 year and 10 year moving averages of my dataset. By using .rolling_mean I can take the average based on what i set the window to, however, as the dates are not sequential, this does not work.

```
Dataframe:
    Date          Count
    1981-01-08    10
    1981-05-12    65
    1982-03-17    96
    1982-09-15    33
    1982-12-01    85
    1983-02-03    14
    .
    .
    . 
    2017-01-28    56

Code: 
counts_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('DATE').size().rename('counts'))
start_date_periods = counts_df.loc[counts_df.index > '1981-01-01']
start_date_periods['5yrMA'] = pd.rolling_mean(start_date_periods, window=5)
start_date_periods['10yrMA'] = pd.rolling_mean(start_date_periods, window=10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those cases of the rolling function working as advertised but not doing what you want it to do. In the latest versions of Pandas you should get a warning when using `rolling_mean` as it's being deprecated in favor of `rolling` so for illustration I'll use `rolling`:

The rolling function is designed to work with any data, not just time series. So it 'looks back' x number of units. The look back is set with the `window` parameter. And it does the look back based on the sort order of the dataframe. So even if you sort your data correctly, `rolling` doesn't know that you mean years when you give it a window of 5... it sees only "look back 5 cells"

So if you want to look back 5 years against data with missing values you need to fill those values with something. You can use `NaN` or you can use one of the many interpolation methods provided by Pandas.  I'll illustrate the `NaN` method:

since you didn't provide some easy to use synthetic data, I set some up:

```
np.random.seed(1)
ts_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6210),
                       index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2016-12-31', freq='D'), 
                       columns=['data']) # index of every day for 7 years

ts_sample = ts_data.sample(n=10).sort_index() ## sample then sort
print ts_sample
```

that returns a nicely sorted example df with 10 values and a date index:

```
               data
2001-07-21  0.107343
2003-07-12  0.658537
2004-08-21 -0.463338
2006-07-13 -0.866955
2011-12-14  0.020956
2012-05-14 -2.685125
2012-12-27  0.494037
2013-06-09 -1.299026
2013-12-12  0.371309
2015-06-17  0.201656
```

so in order to fill in those missing values, let's create a new df with nothing but a full index with all days:

```
full_period = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2016-12-31', freq='D') )
```

Because of how Pandas uses indexes, if you pop our example data into a column, Pandas will fill in missing values with `NaN`:

```
full_period['data'] = ts_sample.data
print full_period['2015-06-16':'2015-06-18']
```

and I'm only printing three days so we can see how it popped the data in:

```
                data
2015-06-16       NaN
2015-06-17  0.201656
2015-06-18       NaN
```

So now we have a full set of daily data with missing data filled with `NaN`. Now we can do the rolling mean:

```
rolling = full_period.rolling(min_periods=1, window=365*5,center=False).mean() # daily data so using 5 years of days
print rolling['2015-06-16':'2015-06-18']
```

and, once again, printing the same 3 values:

```
                data
2015-06-16 -0.619570
2015-06-17 -0.482699
2015-06-18 -0.482699
```

if you want to select back only the rolling average for your original dates, you can do that with a little one liner:

```
print rolling.ix[ts_sample.index.tolist()]

                data
2001-07-21  0.107343
2003-07-12  0.382940
2004-08-21  0.100847
2006-07-13 -0.141103
2011-12-14  0.020956
2012-05-14 -1.332085
2012-12-27 -0.723377
2013-06-09 -0.867290
2013-12-12 -0.619570
2015-06-17 -0.482699
```

Comment: this was super helpful and I appreciate the time you spent on this answer. Just to confirm, if i wanted to calculate the rolling 10-year moving avg I would set window= 365*10 correct?

Comment: if you set each cell in the df to a day, then a year is 365... so yup, 365*10

Answer (score 0):

Sort your dataframe against your index before calculating rolling data.

Answer (score 0):

Using the current rolling function in pandas, you can directly pass the window size of days: rolling('365d') for 1 year, rolling('1826d') for 5 years which takes into account an extra days for leap years (not perfectly accurate but covers majority of cases), rolling('3652d') for 10 years. The mean will be calculated for only the observed data points in the rolling window.

Comment: How does this improve upon the accepted answer?

Comment: A bit shorter perhaps? Actually I had been trying to figure how to do the same thing and thought that the solution was really well explained, but did not work for me. Particularly the rolling.ix[ts_sample.index.tolist()] would not produce any results for me. And I found that passing the number of days would produce the expected result much faster and better. So I shared, hoping it could help anyone else. But feel free to disregard if you prefer.